# Filtering factor in dataframe

Tags: regex, r, filtering

I have this table:

```
Source                     Protocol
10.0.0.6                    IGMPv3
10.0.0.6                    SSDP
fe80::2998:5ae5:5e72:7f9    SSDP
fe80::2998:5ae5:5e72:7f9    SSDP
a0:48:1c:df:1b:1b           ARP
a0:48:1c:df:1b:1b           ARP
10.0.0.11                   TCP
10.0.0.11                   HTTP
Vmware_98:56:e6             ARP
Vmware_98:56:e6             ARP
12.0.0.11                   IGMPv6
23.3.1.11                   BROWSER
```

I need to filter the mac addresses without hard coding it, expected output:

```
Source                     Protocol
10.0.0.6                    HTTP
10.0.0.6                    SSDP
10.0.0.11                   TCP
10.0.0.11                   HTTP
12.0.0.11                   IGMPv6
23.3.1.11                   BROWSER
```

Comment: Does Mac address always starts with `10.0.0.`?

Comment: @DavidArenburg um nope, it can be 200, 12, 30 etc...

Comment: Does it always start with number?

Comment: yes it start with a number , but some mac addresses start with number too

Comment: @sy1993 It is confusing `but some mac addresses start with number too`.  Also, does it always end with a digit?

Comment: @arkrun yes it does. really appreciate you guys helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
  dat[grep("^\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+$",dat$Source),]
  #        Source Protocol
  #1   10.0.0.6   IGMPv3
  #2   10.0.0.6     SSDP
  #7  10.0.0.11      TCP
  #8  10.0.0.11     HTTP
  #11 12.0.0.11   IGMPv6
  #12 23.3.1.11  BROWSER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}.*$)
```

You can try this as well.just grab the matches or groups.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nB2lL9/7

---

**Edit**:
In R it will be something like (assuming `df` is your data set)

```
df[grep("^\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}.*$", df$Source), ]
```